# Single Wordpress site in subfolder/subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a wordpress site that needs to work in a subdirectory : domain.com/dir/subdir/. It's a copy of a site that is in a single subdirectory – domain.com/subdirectory.
The database connection is working fine (content is there) but script urls etc are domain.com/wp-content and not the subdirectory.
Here's what I've tried:
 - updating home and site url in options table
 - different setups in .htaccess setting RewriteBase to /folder/subdir/ (gives me server error)
 - setting site url manually in index.php

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: update once permalinks

Comment: I can't access the backend, so that won't do it.

Comment: i get this when I try to access it:

http://domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fdirectory%2Fsubdir%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1